# Show that $A[T]/(P(T))$ is a local flat A-algebra where $(A,\mathfrak{m},k)$ is a local ring with $k[T]/(\tilde{P}(T))$ is a simple extension of $k$

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, schemes, local-rings

Let $(A,\mathfrak{m},k)$ be a (Noetherian) local ring. Let $k[T]/(\tilde{P}(T))$ be a simple field extension of $k$ with $\tilde{P}(T)$ monic and irreducible (and separable). Lift $\tilde{P}(T)$ to monic $P(T)\in A[T]$. Can we show that $A[T]/(P(T))$ is a flat local $A$-algebra?

The claim is used in Qing Liu's book *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves*, Corollary 5.3.17:

[image: see picture here]

A similar claim is in Exercise 4.3.19:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at a single example? Also, should P be monic?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg No I haven't and I am gonna try. Yes $P$ should be monic, I have updated the post.

Comment: Well, then it is clear that $A[T]/\langle P \rangle$ is a free $A$-module of rank $\mathrm{deg}(P)$, hence it is flat. But locality is a bit difficult. Of course $\mathfrak{m} A[T]/\langle P \rangle$ is a maximal ideal, but it is not clear (to me) why it is the unique one. What about $\mathbb{Z}_2[T]/\langle T^2+T+1 \rangle$, why is it local (where $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the ring $2$-adic integers)?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg  I just found out in the Corollary the locality condition is not used. Though $B:=\mathbb{Z}_2[T]/\langle T^2+T+1\rangle$ should be local: every element out side the maximal ideal is of the form $a+bT$ with $2\nmid a$ or $2\nmid b$. Factoring out the units then it is either $a+T$ or $1+bT$.
 The inverse of $a+T$ in $B$ is $c+dT$ where $c=\frac{-1+a}{1+a(a-1)},d=ac-1$, and the inverse of $1+bT$ is $c+dT$ where $d=\frac{-b}{1+b(b-1)},c=bd+1$.

Comment: Yeah I already mentioned that (you mean P). The hard part is prove that the ring is local (if it is true). I can prove it when P has degree 2.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Check out my answer, I need a second opinion for its validity.

Comment: @ZWu Looks right to me, very nice solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. I mean it indeed seems trivial if you are in the right direction.

Clearly $B:=A[T]/(P(T))$ is a finite free $A$-module with basis $\{1,T,\dots,T^{\mathrm{deg}P-1}\}$. So $A\to B$ is free and thus flat, and in particular, it is a finite ring extension, so $\mathfrak{p}\in \operatorname{Spec}B$ is maximal iff $\mathfrak{p}\cap A$ is maximal, i.e. $\mathfrak{p}\cap A=\mathfrak{m}$. Then the points of $\mathrm{Spec} (B\otimes_A \frac{A}{\mathfrak{m}})=\operatorname{Spec}B \times_{\mathrm{Spec}A}\operatorname{Spec}\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ are exactly the set of prime ideals of $B$ lying over $\mathfrak{m}$, which must be the set of maximal ideals of $B$. Since $$B\otimes_A \frac{A}{\mathfrak{m}}\cong \frac{A[T]}{(P(T))+\mathfrak{m}[T]}\cong\frac{\frac{A}{\mathfrak{m}}[T]}{(\tilde{P}(T))}=\frac{k[T]}{(\tilde{P}(T))}$$ is a field, it has only one prime ideal. So $B$ must be local.